# WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I try to do WebSocket with Javascript, PHP, and Wamp but I have the error "WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state" when I do a send. I have used source code [here](http://sii-rennes.developpez.com/articles/un-chat-en-html5-avec-les-websockets/). I use port 11345, I have tried port 80, with same result. After having initialized socket, the status remains 3. It seems that socket.onopen is never called, but why ?

Seems different from post with the same error found on Stackoverflow. All is in local, I have turned off firewall, running on Chrome 36, currently the latest. Thanks beforehand.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to have a little investigation as to what is going on? (receiving error messages etc)

Comment: Not sure, sorry.. Slightly off-topic, and doesn't necessarily help..but I found this resource to be very useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: With Fiddler, I have only one line : Result to 502; Host set to Tunnel to, url set to localhost:11345, Body set to 518, caching set to no-cache, must-revalidate. When I try to initialize socket, no line is add on Fiddler. About 502 error there is information here, I have clear browser cache, no different result

Comment: Same thing here. WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.